# Why is my NVMe drive only showing up after windows sleeps and wakes?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, ssd, nvme

My hardware:
Gigabyte Aero 15WV8,
HP EX950 NVMe SSD.

I'm going kinda crazy now. I got the EX950 SSD in the mail the other day, installed it in my laptop's NVMe only m.2 slot, it showed up in BIOS under NVMe configuration. I then boot up windows (off of the SATA SSD that came with the laptop) and the drive doesn't show up in device manager. I also tried AntergOS (dual-booted), systemrescuecd (live off of a usb) and the windows installer (off of a usb). None of them could detect the drive (no /dev/nvme* files in linux, nothing on windows device manager). I then tried booting the live usbs (windows installer and systemrescuecd) with only the nvme drive installed (in the NVMe only slot), nothing. I tried the other slot (the SATA/NVMe one), still nothing. I've given up at this point, so I decide to install both drives and boot back into windows. Startup takes a good 10 minutes before the spinning dots show up, then windows boots normally. I then shut my laptop's lid, and when I later open it back up and log in, the HP ssd has shown up as a storage device in windows, and everything is working just fine. The same thing happens after each (10 minute) restart now. No drive when I first log in, then after a sleep/wake cycle, it suddenly shows up.

Ideally I'd like to dual boot windows 10 on the NVME drive and AntergOS on the SATA drive, but the windows installer still doesn't detect the NVMe drive even after I've reformatted it and put some files on it.
Thanks!

Comment: **AntergOS** (not "antegros") like any other desktop Linux does not support SATA modes other than AHCI. But Windows should. If you're experiencing problems you may need to upgrade UEFI (you don't have BIOS) and the SSD firmware. Also, if you're installing Windows and Linux from scratch: 1. Make sure you're booting in UEFI mode and 2. Change the SATA mode to AHCI.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia What gives you the impression, that Linux supports AHCI only?

Comment: It might need a driver. As HP says nothing about it, this [redit post](https://www.reddit.com/user/NewMaxx/comments/akklt1/hp_ex900ex920ex950_drivers_ex920_firmware_updates/) recommends [this driver](https://www.multipointe.com/downloads/). If you intend to try it, create first a system restore point as a way back.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thanks, I fixed the spelling, and I'm already booting in UEFI mode, and the SATA controller is in AHCI mode. I did that before any of the other tests/troubleshooting. I'm already on the most current version of the [UEFI](https://www.gigabyte.com/Laptop/AERO-15--i7-8750H#support-dl-bios) (which gigabyte are referring to as BIOS funnily enough).

Comment: @grawity 1. Sure, I forgot about that one (and ironically  it was the subject of one of my questions) 2. I didn't said NVMe was a SATA mode; "SATA mode" is how most firmwares describe the setting for AHCI, RAID, Intel RST, IDE, etc. Yes, of course Linux supports NVMe but they won't "see" those drives unless the mode is AHCI. 3. This couldn't be an answer yet.

Answer (score -1):

I have a Gigabyte Aero 15X V8 and a HP EX950 2TB SSD. I could not get it working at all until I forced ASPM setting L0s in the SSD instead of ASPM setting L1. I don't recommend this SSD with this laptop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).